# How can I change the order of vertical tabs?

Tags: 7, forms

More specifically, I am using Location in Drupal 7 to allow people to add location to nodes, but I want it to appear at the top of the vertical tabs fieldgroup.

Comment: I just implemented knight approach and uploaded it to github: https://github.com/rogercodina/customize_vt I think knight approach is much better solution than using Renderable Elements because this module says in its home page that is very experimental.

Comment: My module has evolved and is now on drupal.org: https://www.drupal.org/project/vertical_tabs_config

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to user842's answer (for those who are interested in a more code-based solution) is to set the weights on all the form items whose group is "additional_settings". The idea here is, higher the weight, lower the tab will appear, where the default is the one with the lowest weight (or one whose weight is not set).

To do this without modifying core code, [create a module](https://drupal.org/node/361112) with a very large weight (see [weight module](https://drupal.org/project/modules_weight) for a module-based, or [this post](https://drupal.org/node/110238) for a DB-based approach). Specifying the weight is important so that the module can be executed later than other modules which may change the order of the tabs. In this module, implement [`hook_form_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7), or [`hook_node_form_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7), which exposes the `$form` array.

At this point, you can look at the `$form` array, and pick out the indices that correspond to the vertical tabs whose order you wish to edit. One way to look at the `$form` array is by printing it out (via `drupal_set_message($form)` in the `hook_form_alter` or `hook_node_form_alter`). This array is huge, so you may want to run some kind of browser search to find the items that you want.

The indices that correspond to items on the vertical tabs are items with `#group` set to `additional_settings` (so you can search for the string "additional_settings"). For example, you may see the following when you print out the `$form` array:

```
Array
(
   ...
   [path] => Array
        (
           ...
           [#group] => additional_settings
           [#weight] => 314159265359
           ...
        )
)
```

and this is showing that `path` which corresponds to the location tab in the vertical tabs has a large weight 314159265359, which might be the reason that it is showing last in the vertical tabs.

With this info, you can now change the order of this tab in your hook by decreasing the value of the weight:

```
// set a small weight for the path tab
$form['path']['#weight'] = -1;
```

in your hook. Notice that weights can also be negative. You can do this for some/every tab (by going through and changing their weights).

This unfortunately doesn't work for all situations. If the `#weight` of some vertical tab is unset, somehow, that tab will bubble to the top. You can fix that by giving the tab. The source-code might look something like

```
/**
   Implements hook_form_FORMID_alter, hook_node_form_alter.
   Changes the $form array to reorder vertical tabs.
*/
function reorder_vertical_tabs_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
   // move 'location' to the top (as the default)
   $form['path']['#weight'] = -1;

   // move 'themekey' under 'locations'
   $form['themekey_ui_themes']['#weight'] = 0;

   // move 'published/unpublished' down
   $form['options']['#weight'] = 100;
}
```

From experience, I do not think you can change the order of the vertical tabs by setting `$form['#after_build']`. At that point, the order of the vertical tabs are already set.

Answer (score 1):

The [Renderable elements](http://drupal.org/project/rel) module enables you to will make (additional) elements (such as anything in the vertical tabs) available of existing entities on the manage forms/display screens so you can rearrange the fields through Field UI.

Comment: No Drupal 8 version. It's also a "very experimental"module, so I have reservations about using it on a production site.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the [Vertical Tabs Config](https://www.drupal.org/project/vertical_tabs_config) module.

> This module allows you to:
>
> - Hide vertical tabs on add/edit node pages depending on content type    and role.
> - Decide vertical tabs order.

**Warning**

You may need to clear drupal's and/or browsers cache if you don't see any changes after modifying vertical tabs order.

Comment: I tried vertical_tabs_config - even after clearing caches, the order doesn't change. And my custom tabs don't show up on the list.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 10 change order for form Configure block

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 * Set\change VerticalTabs order (Configure block /admin/structure/block/manage/...)
 */
function wt_plus_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    switch($form_id){
    /*Set\change VerticalTabs order*/
        case 'block_form':
            $order = ['request_path', 'user_role', 'php'];
            foreach($order as $key => $value) if( isset($form['visibility'][$value]) ) $form['visibility'][$value]['#weight'] = -(100 - $key);
            break;
    }
}
```