# how to order grouped fields in the sidebar on a node form

Tags: forms

On my old Drupal 7 site, I was able to group a set of fields and display them as a tab in the sidebar. I'm moving it to Drupal 8 and using the adminimal theme. I created groups and am using the details sidebar widget. I'd like my custom groups to appear at the top of the sidebar. I've assigned a weight of -5 in Manage Form Display, but they still appear in the middle of the sidebar (even after clearing caches). Is there a way to control the order of groups in the sidebar, or am I maybe using the wrong widget? Thanks.

I have tried using Vertical Tabs Config, but even after clearing caches, the order is unchanged.

[image: Vertical tabs reorder]

[image: Manage form display]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly what you're asking about, but Manage Form Display page controls the order of widgets on a form (edit page) and Manage Display page controls the actual rendering (view). Maybe you need to take a look at the Manage display page? This split was different in D7.

Comment: Yes, I'm on the manage form display tab. I'm trying to control the edit form for the node. For both my groups, it says "weight: -2" and I'm assuming the default weight is 0, so they should float to the top. Adding to my confusion are the Authored On and Authored By fields, which are displayed in a tab on the form, but aren't indicated as being in a group.

Comment: Can you post screenshots of the Manage form page and the page where you see it not working correctly?

Comment: https://imageshack.com/i/pnGHyz7Np
https://imageshack.com/i/poLLW9pap

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the order of vertical tabs?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12979/how-can-i-change-the-order-of-vertical-tabs)

Comment: I think this is duplicate, you're asking about vertical tabs order: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12979/how-can-i-change-the-order-of-vertical-tabs BTW question updates should go into the question edit, it's easily missed in comments.

Comment: @prkos , no, this was not a duplicate, you seem to have misunderstood the question. You've linked to a drupal7 answer - this is about field groups (and perhaps adminimal) in drupal 8>

Comment: Vertical tabs config module has both D7 and D8 versions. Maybe try to report your issue there? You mentioned you set the weight of your group to -5, but the screenshots is showing -2. What are the weights of the sections that appear above it? Maybe -5 isn't a small enough number.

Answer (score 0):

Using weight -99 makes it appear on top in my installation.

Weight -10 moves it nicely below the 'author' box, which is where I want it.